# How do I pad a number with zeros?

Tags: go

Let's say I want to pad out a number in Go:

```
4 => "004"
23 => "023"
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `"%0xd"` flag to `fmt.Printf` from the [fmt package](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/), where `x` is the number of leading zeros to pad.

```
import "fmt"
fmt.Printf("%03d", 4)    // will print "004"
```

The interface is the same as in C.